# map:cameraTargetLat or cameraZoom in my XML has no effect

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an Android application with a map.

I try to set the default map position to a specific place, so the app don't start with default location (that seems to be 0,0)

But whatever I do, the map still starts in Africa despite the tags:

```
  <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/tools"//or "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto", same result
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        map:cameraTargetLat="50.5863828"
        map:cameraTargetLng="4.0802475"
        map:cameraZoom="11"/>
```

Any idea what could be wrong, I have this behavior in 2 differents and used to give up, but I really would like to set the default position without waiting and doing it programmatically.

[image]

Comment: `xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` works for me but taking [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38465977/unexpected-namespace-map-android-google-maps-api/38466409#38466409) into account

Comment: This is not the same issue. I have no prefix issue.

Comment: Yes, I understand it. I mean that I have it working using `xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` (but with the Ùnexpected namespace prefix` problem)

Answer (score 0):

give your latlng in for move map to your default position,

```
 map.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(23.0225,72.5317) , 14.0f) );
```

and if you want to put marker there then write

```
 map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(23.0225, 72.5315))
    .title("Marker"));
```

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I don't think this really answers my question.. I would like to achieve the move effect via the XML as the doc says.. And I never talked about markers