# Move Camera to a position on a mapview

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a small map view in my contacts activity:
[image]

But I don't know how to move the camera to a specific location, I've done it before on a MapActivity, but don't know how to do it in here. I don't know where to use the moveCamera function because there is no onMapReady like in a MapActivity, appreciate any help guys. The code:

Java:

```
public class Contacts extends AppCompatActivity {
private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Contactos");
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.abili.agriexport2.Contacts">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="25dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.20">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Onde Estamos:"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/miniMap"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="300dp"
                    android:layout_weight="8" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

in xml:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

in code: Declare

```
static final LatLng Your_Location = new LatLng(23.81, 90.41); //Your LatLong
private GoogleMap mMap;
```

then inside `OnCreate()`

```
((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

            mMap = googleMap;
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Your_Location, 15));  //move camera to location
            if (mMap != null) {
                Marker hamburg = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Your_Location));
            }
            // Rest of the stuff you need to do with the map
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
 googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(Latitude, Longitude), 18));
```

Answer (score 2):

@alb You can use the same implementaion as you mentioned you have worked with onMapReadyCallback.
Here are some changes in your code as you have not instantiated the map it is displaying default view

```
public class Contacts extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Contactos");
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.miniMap);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
       case android.R.id.home:
           finish();
           return true;
       default:
           return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.clear();
    //Here locate and move your camera as required
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(locationLatLng, 16.0f));
    }
}
```

Update xml by replacing the map fragment

```
 <fragment
android:id="@+id/miniMap"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="300dp"
android:layout_weight="8"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

As your map is pretty static you can get a cleaner code if you add the camera target and zoom to your XML. Simply add this to your `<fragment>` in your `layout.xml` (changing the coordinates and zoom level to suit your needs):

```
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
map:cameraTargetLat="40"
map:cameraTargetLng="-4"
map:cameraZoom="18"
tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"
```

Note: you need the `tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"` line to fix this [Unexpected namespace "map" - Android Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38465977/unexpected-namespace-map-android-google-maps-api/38466409#38466409)

Answer (score 0):

Write listener to mapfragment

```
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.miniMap);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                //write your moveCamera function here
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using LocationManager and create marker in onLocationChanged listener

```
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        final LatLng latlng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
       createMarker(latlng);
    }

    private void createMarker(LatLng latlng) {
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = null;
        try {
            markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title("Title");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        final Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
 }
```

After creating marker, I have used below code to animate marker when camera is moved:

```
 final LatLngInterpolator latLngInterpolator = new LatLngInterpolator.LinearFixed();

    final LatLng startPosition = marker.getPosition();
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();
    final float durationInMs = 3000;

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        long elapsed;
        float t;
        float v;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Calculate progress using interpolator
            elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
            t = elapsed / durationInMs;
            v = interpolator.getInterpolation(t);
            marker.setPosition(latLngInterpolator.interpolate(v, startPosition, googleMap.getCameraPosition().target));

            if (t < 1) {
                // Post again 16ms later.
                handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
            }
        }
    });
```